# Magento issue in applying <optgroup> into gride filter drop down

Tags: magento

I have a category column in the grid filters. I need to add  into that category column drop down. I created a type class also, but when calls in prepareColumn function, those are not applying. Create column is as in below:

```
$options = Mage::getModel('productsync/categorymapping_system_config_source_catalog_categorypaths')
                    ->toOptionArray();


    $this->addColumn(
        'category',
        array(
            'header'   => Mage::helper('productsync')->__('Category'),
            'width'    => '1',
            'type'     => 'options',
            'index'    => 'category_id',
            'editable' => true,
            'options'  => $options,
            'renderer' => 'productsync/adminhtml_categorymapping_widget_grid_column_renderer_options',
            'filter_condition_callback'
                            => array($this, '_filterCategoriesCondition'),
        )
    );
```

Can anyone please tell me what is issue with this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within Magento's **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Select** class and the **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Options** class.

Reviewing the getHtml() method of the Filter class, it looks like they did in fact write this method with the anticipation to support `<optgroup>`, however where they failed is in the _getOptions() method of that class. Here we can see that they build it into a 2 dimensional array no matter what format the options data was already supplied in. In your case, I'm assuming your options are already in a format that contain a "label", "value" structure to your `$options` variable.

Magento's Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Options class on the other hand does not appear to have ever been written to support options that utilize `optgroup`.

To address this, we can rewrite these classes with some additional logic to support what we're looking for.

**Note:** You have not included any information regarding your renderer class you are specifying (adminhtml_categorymapping_widget_grid_column_renderer_options), so I'm not sure what you may be doing with that class that is separate from any other grid column of the type "options". My solution that follows will simply allow a column of this type to support option groups.

**Step 1:** Create our extension definition file: 
`app/code/etc/modules/StackOverflow_Question27633881.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackOverflow_Question27633881>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </StackOverflow_Question27633881>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create our extension's configuration file, which contains instructions to rewrite the two Mage classes mentioned above:
`app/code/local/StackOverflow/Question27633881/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackOverflow_Question27633881>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackOverflow_Question27633881>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <!-- Rewrites -->
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                   <widget_grid_column_filter_select>StackOverflow_Question27633881_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Select</widget_grid_column_filter_select>
                   <widget_grid_column_renderer_options>StackOverflow_Question27633881_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Options</widget_grid_column_renderer_options>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step 3**: Create our new filter class with updated logic
`app/code/local/StackOverflow/Question27633881/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Select.php`

```
<?php
class StackOverflow_Question27633881_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Select
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Select
{
    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Select::_getOptions()
     */
    protected function _getOptions()
    {
        $emptyOption = array('value' => null, 'label' => '');

        $optionGroups = $this->getColumn()->getOptionGroups();
        if ($optionGroups) {
            array_unshift($optionGroups, $emptyOption);
            return $optionGroups;
        }

        $colOptions = $this->getColumn()->getOptions();

        // Options have already been setup in a way that is "label" / "value" format. Don't mess with it any further
        if (isset($colOptions[0]) && isset($colOptions[0]['label'])) {
            return $colOptions;
        }

        if (!empty($colOptions) && is_array($colOptions) ) {
            $options = array($emptyOption);
            foreach ($colOptions as $value => $label) {
                $options[] = array('value' => $value, 'label' => $label);
            }
            return $options;
        }
        return array();
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** Create our new render class with updated logic:
`app/code/local/StackOverflow/Question27633881/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Options.php`

```
<?php
class StackOverflow_Question27633881_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Options
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Options
{
    /**
     * Render a grid cell as options
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $options = $this->getColumn()->getOptions();
        $showMissingOptionValues = (bool)$this->getColumn()->getShowMissingOptionValues();
        if (!empty($options) && is_array($options)) {

            // Call our new function if necessary.
            if (   isset($options[0]) && isset($options[0]['value'])
                || isset($options[1]) && isset($options[1]['value'])
            ) {
                $options = $this->_getFlatOptions($options);
            }

            $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());

            if (is_array($value)) {
                $res = array();
                foreach ($value as $item) {
                    if (isset($options[$item])) {
                        $res[] = $this->escapeHtml($options[$item]);
                    }
                    elseif ($showMissingOptionValues) {
                        $res[] = $this->escapeHtml($item);
                    }
                }
                return implode(', ', $res);
            } elseif (isset($options[$value])) {
                return $this->escapeHtml($options[$value]);
            } elseif (in_array($value, $options)) {
                return $this->escapeHtml($value);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Our new function that will turn a set of options with option groups, to a flat array of options.
     *
     * @param array $grouped_options
     */
    protected function _getFlatOptions($grouped_options)
    {
        $options = array();

        foreach ($grouped_options as $option) {
            if ('' == $option['value'] || null === $option['value']) {
                continue;
            }

            if (is_string($option['value'])) {
                $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
            } elseif (is_array($option['value'])) {
                foreach ($option['value'] as $opt) {
                    $options[$opt['value']] = $opt['label'];
                }
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

Afterwards, flush Magento's `Configuration` cache type if it is enabled.